# how to rename the joomla administrator folder

Tags: php, joomla, xss

I want to rename the `joomla` administrator folder to other name to prevent the hacking from identifying the site is built of `joomla` . But i have tried [this](http://www.joomlahackers.net/joomla-tutorials/change-joomla-admin-name-or-path.html) way.

in it, they are using cookies . Is it affect the site?

is there any better way to rename the administrator folder.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had the same issue before.Please do not rename it,you will face lots of problem for this.I have solve this issue by redirecting the path.Use {header} to redirect your admin path in index file.

Answer (score 3):

You can't really change it as it would prevent extensions from installing properly. You can however use Admin Exile which allows you to add a value, key or both to the administrator URL. In addition to this, if the standard admin URL is typed it, it will redirect the user to a site of your choice.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/login-protection/15711

Hope this helps